# How to define a PHP object as the last item in an array?

Tags: php

In the code below I want to apply the object "$activeclass" as a DIV class.  I thought the end pointer I included would apply this only to the last iteration of the array, but instead it is applying the class to all iterations.

```
<div id="right_bottom">
                <?
                $content = is_array($pagedata->content) ? $pagedata->content : array($pagedata->content);
                foreach($content as $item){
                $activeclass = end($content) ? 'active' : ' ';
                    ?>
                    <div id="right_side">
                           <div id="<?=$item->id?>" class="side_items <?=$activeclass?>">
                             <a class="content" href="<?=$item->id?>"><img src="<?=PROTOCOL?>//<?=DOMAIN?>/img/content/<?=$item->image?>"><br />
                             <strong><?=$item->title?></strong></a><br />
                             <h2><?=date('F j, Y',  strtotime($item->published))?></h2><br />
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <?
                }
                ?>
</div>
```

Any ideas where I am making a mistake?  How can I apply the class $activeclass only to the last iteration of my "foreach" statement?

Comment: end($content) does not what you think it does!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to keep a count:

```
$i = 0; $size = count( $content);
foreach( $content as $item) {
    $i++;
    $activeclass = ( $i < $size) ? '' : 'active';
}
```

Alternatively, you can compare the last element with the current element (if your array is consecutively numerically indexed starting with 0 [Thanks to webbiedave for pointing out the assumptions made by this method]):

```
$last = count( $content) - 1;
foreach( $content as $item) {
    $activeclass = ( $content[$last] === $item) ? 'active' : '';
}
```

Note that this approach will not work if your array has duplicate items.

Finally, you can compare indexes in the following way:

```
// Numerical or associative
$keys = array_keys($content); 
$key = array_pop($keys); // Assigned to variables thanks to webbiedave

// Consecutive numerically indexed
$key = count( $content) - 1; 

foreach( $content as $current_key => $item) {
    $activeclass = ( $current_key === $key) ? 'active' : '';
}
```

Comment: Regarding your `$content[$size]` approach, is there evidence that the arrays are numerically indexed and guaranteed to be consecutive?

Comment: +1 For adding the last example that grabs the last key regardless of indexing scheme. The only thing I would add is that you'll receive a `Strict Standards` warning which can be avoided by assigning to a variable first, e.g.: `$keys = array_keys($content); $lastKey = array_pop($keys);`

Comment: I really need to turn on those messages on my dev setup... Thanks

Comment: The second option worked perfect for my needs.  It's worth pointing out that you put `$size` when I think you meant `$last`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$activeclass = end($content) ? 'active' : ' ';
```

The `end()` function returns the last element in the array, so you're basically checking to see if the array has a last element (which it always will, unless it's empty).

This is an explanation of what you're doing wrong - nick has the answer for how to fix it by using a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach from the following link http://blog.actsmedia.com/2009/09/php-foreach-last-item-last-loop/

```
$last_item = end($array);
$last_item = each($array);
reset($array);
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    // code executed during standard iteration
    if($value == $last_item['value'] && $key == $last_item['key'])
    {
    // code executed on the 
            // last iteration of the foreach loop
    }
 }
```